# C# Get IP assigned by router

Tags: c#, networking, ip-address, router

I don't know if I'm just not searching using the right keywords, I want to be able to find the IP address of my local computer that was assigned by my router.

I was using:

```
IPHostEntry host;
host = Dns.GetHostEntry(Dns.GetHostName());

foreach(IPAddress ip in host.AddressList)
{
   if(ip.addressfamily.tostring() == "InterNetwork")
   {
      return ip;
   }
}
```

The problem is I have multiple InterNetwork ip addresses because I use virtual services, so I need to be able to identify which one was assigned by my router.

Comment: The answers in this question should cover most of your options: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1069103/how-to-get-my-own-ip-address-in-c?rq=1

Comment: Why won't you compare against the enum System.Net.Sockets.AddressFamily.InterNetwork?

Comment: i changed it to that, doesnt change anything

Comment: no, it shouldn't, just was curious if there was a reason :)

Answer (score 0):

How about loopback?

```
if (IPAddress.IsLoopback(ip)) return ip; //localhost
```

Or try pinging the local machine

```
Ping pingSender = new Ping ();
IPAddress address = IPAddress.Loopback;
PingReply reply = pingSender.Send (address);
if (reply.Status == IPStatus.Success){..}
```

also this might help you

[Showing The External IP-Address In C#](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/24692-showing-the-external-ip-address-in-c#/)

Comment: this still doesnt single out the ip address that was assigned by the router

Comment: I'm not sure what is the question then, do you want to know the IP address of your router that faces the Internet? 
in most cases the first ip in the collection of ips is the external interface of your router

Comment: I think I found a solution, I'll post it up as the answer once I do a couple tests and see if it's legit.  Will be using http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4553453/how-to-get-ip-address-in-c for the solution